# Um eventListener constante, ou quase isso

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sempre fiquei em dúvida quando a isso, pois lembro que fazia meus teste com ajax, e toda vez que atualizava, perdia o evento registrado.

Exemplo:
Um lista de nomes

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".clickLi").click(function(){
            console.log($(this).data("age"));
        });
    });
</script>
<ul>
    <li class="clickLi" data-age="18">Nome 1</li>
    <li class="clickLi" data-age="6">Nome 2</li>
    <li class="clickLi" data-age="32">Nome 3</li>
</ul>
```

Nesse código, após clicar em um li, a idade vai ser escrita no console.

Ok, mas e se tivesse um botão que, por ajax, atualizasse essa lista, perderia a função de click. Como eu faço pra manter um listener na lista?

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

A solução para isso é não adicionar os *listeners* em elementos que serão removidos/substituídos (ou que ainda nem existam), e sim em um elemento anterior a eles na hierarquia, cuja existência seja garantida a qualquer momento.

Por exemplo, a sua operação Ajax altera apenas o conteúdo da `<ul>`, você pode colocar o *listener* na própria `<ul>` em vez de colocar nos listeners individuais. Em último caso, você coloca no próprio *body* do documento, pois esse sempre existe e é ancestral de qualquer outro elemento. Como o evento de clique "borbulha" pela hierarquia do DOM, o evento pode ser capturado num nível mais acima.

Isso se chama **delegação de eventos**, e o jQuery oferece uma sintaxe para isso que torna a operação bem simples:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.clickLi', function(e) {
    $(e.target).data("age")
});
```

O segundo parâmetro do `.on()` é o seletor dos elementos-alvo, que podem ou não existir no momento em que o *listener* é criado é adicionado ao `<ul>`.

Repare também que dentro da função eu troquei `$(this)` por `$(e.target)`. Isso porque `$(this)` seria a própria lista, a `<ul>`, enquanto `$(e.target)` será o elemento clicado (o `<li>` com a classe `clickLi`).

Segue uma reprodução simples:

```js
// Deixa de funcionar se os LI forem substituídos
$('.clickme').click(function(e) {
  var $e = $(e.target);
  $e.text(Math.random());
});

// Sempre funciona
$('ul').on('click', '.clickme', function(e) {
  var $e = $(e.target);
  $e.css('color', 'blue');
});

$('.breakThePage').click(breakThePage);
$('.fixThePage').click(fixThePage);

// Reinsere listeners para cada elemento
function fixThePage() {
  $('.clickme').off();
  $('.clickme').click(function(e) {
    var $e = $(e.target);
    $e.text(Math.random());
  });
}

function breakThePage() {
  var $ul = $('ul');
  $ul.html(
    '<li class="clickme">1</li>' +
    '<li class="clickme">2</li>' +
    '<li class="clickme">3</li>' +
    '<li class="clickme">4</li>' +
    '<li class="clickme">5</li>'
  );
}

function dontBreakThePage() {
  var $li = $('li:nth-child(3)');
  $li.text('Changed o.O');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="clickme">1</li>
  <li class="clickme">2</li>
  <li class="clickme">3</li>
  <li class="clickme">4</li>
  <li class="clickme">5</li>
</ul>

<button class="breakThePage">Eu quebro a página</button>
<button class="fixThePage">Eu conserto a página</button>
```

Comment: Agradeço ao @yamadapc pelo exemplo funcional (adaptei o que estava na sua sugestão de edição).

Comment: Boa ideia, de usar uma cor diferente, ao invés dos meus muitos botões. Tentei pensar em algo assim, mas não veio a cabeça por algum motivo :)